# How to prove that C(X, Y) is completely regular but not normal?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be any topological space and $(Y, d)$ a metric space. Endow both the space of all maps $Y^X$ and the space of continuous maps $C(X, Y)$ with the topology of compact convergence, i.e. the basis elements are of the form

$$ B_K(f, \epsilon) = \{ g \in Y^X \,|\, \forall x \in K, d(f(x), g(x)) < \epsilon \} $$

where $ f \in Y^X $, $ \epsilon > 0 $ and $K \subseteq X$ is a compact set. Replace $Y^X$ by $C(X, Y)$ in case of $C(X, Y)$.

The problems are as follows:

1. Prove that $Y^X$ is Hausdorff.
2. Give an example in which $Y^X$ is not regular.
3. Prove that $C(X, Y)$ is completely regular.
4. Give an example in which $C(X, Y)$ is not normal.

I know how to prove statement 1: Let $f, g \in Y^X$ be two distinct elements. There exists $a \in X$ such that $f(a) \neq g(a)$. Let $K = \{a\}$ and $ \epsilon = d(f(a), g(a)) / 2 $. Then $ B_K(f, \epsilon) $ and $ B_K(g, \epsilon) $ are disjoint neighbourhoods of $f$ and $g$ respectively.

However, I have no idea how to prove statements 2, 3, 4. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: For $2$ use a space that is not locally compact like $\Bbb Q$.  Show for 3 that we have defined a uniformity on $C(X,Y)$, or a collection of pseudometrics generates the topology (another view) 4. $X$ discrete uncountable and $Y=\Bbb R$ will give $\Bbb R^X$ in the product topology as $C(X,Y)$, which is well-known to be non-normal.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. Could you give a full answer for 3? I haven't learnt about the notion of uniformity.

Comment: The pseudometrics could also help. It's the same idea in essence. You used the tag functional analysis which would cover such ideas (a good course anyway)>